# std::make_shared an interface?

Tags: c++, interface

I have a Component class who inherits from IComponent. This function link a component with antoher.

```cpp
    void Component::link(IComponent &other)
    {
        components->setRef(std::make_shared<IComponent>(other));
    }
```

When I compile my program I have this error :

```
error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘IComponent’
```

How can I fix this?

PS: I understand that I can't instantiate an Interface because she's contain pure virtual function, but I don't know how to avoid this problem

Comment: `make_shared` makes a new instance of an object, it's not what you want. `Component::link` should receive `shared_ptr<IComponent>` as argument.

Comment: Where does `other` come from? Do you mean to transfer its ownership to `shared_ptr`? If so, pass it by rvalue ref directly to `setRef`.

Comment: I understand that, but my teacher is imposing the prototype of the function

Comment: Usually you would add a pure virtual `clone` method to your interface and implement it in the derived classes

Comment: Thanks it's working !

Answer (score 0):

It's quite unclear what you trying to do here. "setRef()" sounds like its argument is a reference, if so you don't need to do anything with (smart) pointers.  You should at least show the prototype of that method.

As noted above, if you want to "make a copy" of "other" you should do it by "cloning" interface, e.g. create virtual "IComponent* IComponent::clone()" method and implement it properly in Component.
Also if it's guaranteed "other" is a reference to Component that you can cast and copy-construct the new instance (but that's unlikely what your teacher wants you too do).